How can create a TextFormField allowing users to input values via keyboard, also while tapping the suffixIcon reveals a dropdown menu for selection
I want to make a DropdownTextField where the user can choose either keyboard or dropdown to input value in the field.
I want to achieve a TextFormField where the user can give input value with the keyboard and if the user presses the suffixIcon a dropdown will appear and can also select a value from the dropdown menu.

This is what I want to make, but the dropdown should take the full width like the last photo.


Have you tried this package: https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_textfield?

Please share your current reproducible code to give more information here for anyone to be able to help

I already tried this package. I want a dropDownTextField where user can input value using keyboard or selecting dropdown item as there wish.
